# How to use collect(.byTime) or collect(.byTimeOrCount) in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

```
publisher.collect(<#T##strategy: Publishers.TimeGroupingStrategy<Scheduler>##Publishers.TimeGroupingStrategy<Scheduler>#>)
```

I couldn't find any example anywhere and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/timegroupingstrategy) is bland... free [Using Combine](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-collectbytime) book has nothing interesting as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Xcode 11.3, the completion doesn't work extremely well, but the format isn't too complex. There are two options (as of iOS 13.3) that are published in the [TimeGroupingStrategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/timegroupingstrategy) enumeration:

- `byTime`
- `byTimeOrCount`

When you specify either of the strategies, you will also need to specify a scheduler that it runs upon, which is one of the parameters to those enumeration cases.

For example, to collect by time, with a 1.0 second interval of collection, using a DispatchQueue, you might use:

```swift
let q = DispatchQueue(label: self.debugDescription)

let cancellable = publisher
    .collect(.byTime(q, 1.0))
```

The `byTime` version will use an unbounded amount of memory during the  interval specified in buffering values provided by upstream publishers.

The `byTimeOrCount` takes an additional `count` parameter which puts an upper bound on the number of items collected before the buffered collection is sent to subscribers.

For example, the same code with a 10 item max buffer size:

```swift
let q = DispatchQueue(label: self.debugDescription)

let cancellable = publisher
    .collect(.byTimeOrCount(q, 1.0, 10))
```

You can see more specific examples of the code being used, and unit tests verifying how they're operating, in the [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) project:

- [testCollectByTime](https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/UsingCombineTests/ReducingOperatorTests.swift#L289)
- [testCollectByTimeOrCount](https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/UsingCombineTests/ReducingOperatorTests.swift#L352)